# Loading private images takes too long in symfony3

Tags: nginx, symfony

I serve protected images via controller, so that I can disable some of them from public view when needed. Therefore I'm using BinaryFileResponse, and actually serve image directly from Nginx.
Here is the controller:

```
public function getPictureAction(Request $request, $id)
{
        $image = $this->getDoctrine()
                      ->getRepository('AppBundle:Images')
                      ->getOneById($id);

        $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/';

        // Serving image by using Nginx's 'XSendfile'
        $request->headers->set('X-Sendfile-Type', 'X-Accel-Redirect');
        $request->headers->set('X-Accel-Mapping', $dir . '=/images-internal/');
        BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();

        $path = $dir . 'images/image.jpg';
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);

        return $response;
}
```

Part of nginx config where X-Accel-Redirect is enabled:

```
location /images-internal/ {
    internal;
    alias   /home/vagrant/Sites/Symfony/app/;
}
```

Route in routing.yml:

```
picture_path:
    path: /images/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Pages/Home:getPicture, _format: html}
    methods: [GET]
    options:
        expose: true
```

In Twig template I load image like this:

```
<img src="{{ path('picture_path', {'id': imageId}) }}">
```

With this setup the average loading time of an **53KB** image is around **700ms**.

For testing purpose I've loaded the same image using Twig's AssetExtension from public web directory:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/img/image.jpg') }}">
```

And the load time is just **30ms**!

Is it normal that it takes so long to load an image via controller, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on loading time for another controllers. I mean controllers that return regular responses, not binary. If their load time is 700ms or more it is normal.

Loading images from public web directory is fast because only web-server (nginx) is involved.

Loading images via controller involves web-server (nginx), php, symfony. So it ussualy takes same time as requests to regular controllers.

`X-Accel-Redirect` won't help much in this case, it is usually using for huge files to free php processes. Php process sends this header and terminates handling, then nginx reads and sends the file.

If you want to speed up images loading try to install php opcache or write script on pure php without symfony that will handle images download.

Comment: Thanks you for response. I was looking to performance in profiler and saw that Symfony firewall takes about 500ms. So it looks that something wrong happens with the firewall.